# Using federated tables to connect MySQL to MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, federated

Can I use federated tables to make the integration of mysql and mssql ?
I tried and it worked mysql to mysql , but if I try to connect to mssql , do not work.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

As per [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual - 15.8.1 FEDERATED Storage Engine Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-description.html):

> The local server communicates with the remote server using MySQL client C API functions.

... which, naturally, can only connect to `mysqld`.

[MySQL Workbench - Database Migration: Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,525258) gives an overview of options to transfer data between mssql and mysql. They can be summarized as:

1. Access `mysql` from `mssql` through ODBC by adding the former as a "linked server"
2. Transfer data between the two (either direction) with IDEs (by hand, i.e. one-time)
3. Transfer data between the two (either direction) with a program that can access both, possibly including data conversion

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you some way to do this integration?